# How to approximate the Chebychev $\psi$ function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Using  Riemann-Stieltjes integration the following expression is true

$$\theta(n) = \log (t) \pi(t) \Big|_2^n - \int_2^n \frac{\pi(t)}{t}dt. \tag{1}$$

using $Li(x)$ leads to the approximation $\theta(n) \approx n $.

1) So I'm wondering using similar methods (probably based on prime number theory $\pi(x)$) if one can approximates the Chebychev $\psi(n)$ function?

2) If not is it possible and how?

Comment: Using $\operatorname{Li}(x)$ as an approximation to $\pi(x)$ gives the correct $\theta(n) \approx n$, namely $$\log (t)\operatorname{Li}(t)\Bigr\rvert_2^n - \int_2^n \frac{\operatorname{Li}(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_2^n \log (t)\operatorname{Li}'(t) + \frac{\operatorname{Li}(t)}{t}\,dt - \int_2^n \frac{\operatorname{Li}(t)}{t}\,dt = n-2\,.$$ You can use an approximation to $\theta$ to approximate $\psi$, since $$\psi(x) = \theta(x) + \theta(\sqrt{x}) + \theta(\sqrt[3]{x}) + \theta(\sqrt[4]{x}) + \dotsc$$ where only finitely many terms on the right are nozero.

Comment: yes this result is pointed to in Ingham  in APPROXIMATE FORMULAS FOR SOME FUNCTIONS OF PRIME NUMBERS by J. BARKLEY ROSSER AND LOWELL SCHOENFELD. Wondered if anything as nice as (1) had come to light since 1961.

Comment: $\psi$ corresponds to the weighted prime power counting function $\pi^{\ast}(x) = \pi(x) + \frac{1}{2}\pi(\sqrt{x}) + \frac{1}{3}\pi(\sqrt[3]{x}) + \dotsc$ like $\theta$ corresponds to $\pi$. So you get the similar $$\psi(n) = \log(t)\pi^{\ast}(t)\Bigr\rvert_2^n - \int_2^n \frac{\pi^{\ast}(t)}{t}\,dt\,.$$